# How to change loaded element ID from other file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To be precise:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('.mov_c').append('<div class="move_1" id="vid_c_'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#vid_c_'+i).append('<div class="move_2"></div>');
    $(".move_2").load("cntent.html", function (){
        $('#theelement').attr("id", "id_"+i);
    });
}
```

cntent.html:

```
<div class="theelement" id="theelement"></div>
```

New Udate:

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
  $(".move_2").load("cntent.html", (function (x){
     $('.#theelement').attr("id", "id_"+x);
            console.log("Index: "+x); // output values are from 1 to 10
     })(i));
  }
}
```

Didn't worked

Basically I want each time `cntent.html` is called my `theelement` just created id to change to `i` value. The problem with the way i'm doing it is that it changes the whole elements id to just `id_10`, But I want `theelement`s ID to change based on `for` loop value, saying: element one with id of `id_1`, element two with id of `id_2` and so on.

Regards

Comment: can you show us your HTML. and let us know what you are exactly trying to achive? You are making 10 AJAX calls => loading content in certain DIV and trying to change id of one element. Does your "#threeelement" is in your main view or it is part of your response?

Comment: from above code I don' think you will ever have 10 different `theelement` at the same time on page. Because whenever `.load` method's success callback will get called; your previously added `theelement` will get wiped out and new html element will come and sit inside `.move_2`. Please think on it

Comment: how many element you have on your container page having class `move_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It problem with async loaded data and closure. Wrap your code with IIFE to use closure in proper way

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $(".move_2").load("cntent.html", (function (index){
        return function() {
            $('#theelement').attr("id", "id_"+ index);
        }
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: don't know why but this doesn't even changes element ids

Comment: try `concole.log` before setting attrbite to ensure you have correct id here. What log shows?

Comment: Already have it `console.log("index:"+index)` the values are from 1 to 10,

Comment: And what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve, could you clarify?

Comment: Just index values are showing proper but the element id doesn't get changed at all

Comment: Please check this fiddle. After loading content id is changed for entire component. Seems it works as expected. Maybe you have several components with the same id? Try to find on your page. http://jsfiddle.net/vxdHs/476/

Comment: You forgot to add `for loop` in jsfiddle

Comment: Seems I gor where is the problem. Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/vxdHs/478/. I've updated description. Please check

Comment: thousand apologies for my late reply, In your jsfiddle there is just one table `TableItemDetail` but what if you load the same table `for (i)` times and change each table id with value of `i`? I would really appreciate if you do that.

Comment: Currently it loads 10 times, but each new load uodates previous. Do you mean append all 10, not replace?

Comment: Check this updated fiddle - it uses append to generate 10 tables with 10 unique Id's

Comment: yes that is what i mean not to replace and append 10 tables, and I think you forgot to put the fiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

Give similar class name for all elements you want to iterate.
And iterate through all the elements.
Use `this` keyword to change the `id`.

```
<div class="CONTAINER_NAME">
    <div class="COMMAN" id="a"></div>
    <div class="COMMAN" id="b"></div>
    <div class="COMMAN" id="c"></div>
</div>

$('.CONTAINER_NAME .COMMAN_CLASS_NAME').each(function(index){

 $(this).attr("id", "id_"+index);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try following way:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('.mov_c').append('<div class="move_1" id="vid_c_'+i+'"></div>');

    var move2Div = $('<div class="move_2" data-index="'+i+'"></div>'); //defining move_2 separately with data-index holding the index value

    $('#vid_c_'+i).append(move2Div);
    $(move2Div).load("cntent.html", function (){
        var currentIndex = $(this).data("index"); //grabbing the data-index value
        $('#theelement').attr("id", "id_"+currentIndex); //updating the id with required one
    });
 }
```

Comment: This can result in random behavior based on the order of execution of the callback methods. Not a good idea ...

Comment: i don't think so. counter will increment only if we get the response back.

Comment: True, but in which order are the responses obtained? This depends on the server and on the connection to the server. There is absolutely no guarantee that the responses will be processed in the same order as the requests were made. Sure, if the order does not matter then this is a way to go. However we do not know (from the question) if the order matters or not so better assume it does.

Comment: so i guess it equally applicable to your proposed answer... ;)!

Comment: prove it @Anton with real ajax call.

Comment: I already given a reason. I think you haven't able to catch it...!

Comment: @vijayP  still all elements ids are id_10 no changes

Comment: @user3596474 - can you please responds to my comment which i written against your question? I guess it will be good if you can share complete relevant code.

Comment: @user3596474 - have you got a chance to see this updated answer. I guess it will be helpful to you.